# Is there a good resource for data on Ruby Enterprise Edition usage in the wild?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, passenger, interpreter, ruby-enterprise-edition

We're having great results with the Phusion stack ([Passenger](http://www.modrails.com/) and [Ruby Enterprise Edition](http://www.rubyenterpriseedition.com/index.html)) in house, but I haven't been able to find much in the way of data on their use in the wild, particularly REE. I'd love something akin to WWR's [High Profile Organizations Using Rails](http://www.workingwithrails.com/high-profile-organisations) or Ben Forta's [Who's Using ColdFusion?](http://www.forta.com/cf/using/list.cfm) list.

There's some [google group](http://groups.google.com/group/phusion-passenger/browse_thread/thread/521dd6281331dd9e/eeee266cad1d3e70?#eeee266cad1d3e70) activity on this, but I'm looking for something more, for lack of a better word, PHB-friendly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Passenger is being used by a lot of people including Engine Yard.

REE does not have as widespread adoption.

But the same was true of jRuby before too, now many are using it.

Comment: Hey! Nice to see you here. Met you at RailsConf earlier this year.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend against REE, have had stability issues with it giving me malloc errors when i used script/console.

Can't provide a set of instructions on how to replicate it. Just seemed to happen.